# Github Actions: unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat

Tags: docker, github, github-actions

So I've created a GitHub action that is supposed to build and push a docker image to docker hub whenever a push occurs. So here is my GitHub action: (first time creating a GitHub action)

```
name: Some name

on:
  push:

jobs:
  build_frontend:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Build frontend image
        run: docker image build -t image .

      - name: Push frontend image
        uses: elgohr/Publish-Docker-Github-Action@2.14
        with:
          name: image
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_TOKEN }}
```

But I get this error every time this runs:

unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat /home/runner/work/project/project/Dockerfile: no such file or directory
[error]Process completed with exit code 1.

I tried fiddling around with the path, but then I only get no such file or directory. So this is the closest I am to something working.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I believe you need to use the checkout action. Your repository isn't actually available to you until you do that:

So, before "Build frontend image":

```
  - name: Check out code
    uses: actions/checkout@v2
```

Since your Dockerfile is in your root, that should do it.

Comment: That worked thanks! I thought it did that by default. Coming from gitlab-ci you see.

Comment: How does this behaviour differ if the Dockerfile is not in root?

Comment: That's more of a use of docker, but just 'cd' to the directory where your Dockerfile is, or wherever you want your docker context to be.

Answer (score 4):

I think what happens is that it runs on the top level, so if your docker file isn't there, it won't find it and you'll get an error.

For instance, I had a structure that looked like this:

```
-main\
---myProjectFolder\
-----DockerFile
```

and was getting this same error. I then made sure in my actions yml file that I changed to the correct directory before building:

```
run:
 cd myProjectFolder
 docker build -t .
```

So I would suggest trying to get into whatever folder your Dockerfile is in before running docker build.

Comment: The dockerfile is in the root directory. So it should be available as it is, I also tried specifying the whole path that github uses and I got the same error. I also tried using a fake path and then the only error I got was that the dockerfile wasn't found. So really not sure what is causing this

Answer (score 0):

```
      context: "{{defaultContext}}:backend"
```

https://github.com/docker/build-push-action#git-context